# Filtering (searching) database results in Scala Play application

Tags: scala, search, filter, playframework, model

I am building an e-commerce application in Scala Play framework.
I have a model "Product" that might be filtered by different parameters like: Brand, Price, Name, Color and so on.

I'd like to ask, what is the best approach to do so ? 
May i use url query params:

```
/products/filter?brand=XXX&minPrice=100&maxPrice=400
```

Or there is a better way ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have your models stored as a List, applying `filter()` to it would be the most obvious thing to do.

Comment: @Mironor My models are stored as a List. I'm pretty comfortable with applying filter(), however my question is how to properly implement routes to include filtering. Please let me know if i'm clear.

Comment: It is entirely possible to use the route you provided. You could also use a route like `/products/:brand/price/:min/:max` but it is entirely a matter of taste.

Comment: i would recommend to use query params as you exemplified